# Group by three common elements (XML to XML)

Tags: xslt-2.0

We have a requirement in which we need to group by segments which are sharing three things common...I have attached the sample input and  desire output..It would be great if someone help.

We need to make a group on the basis of Country, company name and Month of birth.

I have tried  and I am beginner in this...so couldn't succeeded.

This is our input

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<EMPDTLS>

    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Mathew</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>DEC</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>B</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Luis</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Phillip</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>DEC</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Nick</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Tatar</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JAN</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>CTS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Zuza</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Bark</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JUNE</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Jane</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>ellis</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>ENGLAND</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JUNE</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
        <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>SANJAY</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>BAWARI</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>ENGLAND</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JUNE</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>B</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Akhi</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Mahe</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>SEPT</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Vishh</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Bombard</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>GERMANY</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>OCT</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Sharon</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Watson</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JULY</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>CTS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>B</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Poo</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>SEPT</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>CTS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>DEC</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>

</EMPDTLS>  






<Desired Output>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<EMPDTLS>
<EmpGrp>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Mathew</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>DEC</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>B</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Luis</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Phillip</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>INDIA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>DEC</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>TCS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
</EmpGrp>
<EmpGrp>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Nick</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Tatar</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JAN</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>CTS</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
</EmpGrp>
<EmpGrp>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>Jane</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>ellis</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>ENGLAND</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JUNE</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>A</BAND>
    </EMP>
    <EMP>
        <FIRST_NAME>SANJAY</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>BAWARI</LAST_NAME>
        <COUNTRY>ENGLAND</COUNTRY>
        <MONTH_OF_BIRTH>JUNE</MONTH_OF_BIRTH>
        <COMPANY_NAME>IBM</COMPANY_NAME>
        <BAND>B</BAND>
    </EMP>
</EmpGrp>
```

**

Comment: Please don't embed images of text - put actual XML in the question.

Comment: Hello Matt, Thanks for looking into this..I tried but it was not taking the proper XML..Hence I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: You can paste the XML into the page - check the formatting help for more information.

Comment: Well, even the spec (linking to XSLT 3 as it is the current version and provides composite grouping) has an example doing that in the second example in the section https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples. So select your `xsl:for-each-group select="//EMP" composite="yes" group-by="COUNTRY, COMPANY_NAME, MONTH_OF_BIRTH"` and you can do it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So is it like we can not achieve the same in version 1.0 and 2.0 ?... Also, I am using http://xsltransform.net/ for testing..do we have any different editor for XML 3.0 ? I have tried and it's not working for me..Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composite grouping keys are a bit easier in XSLT 3 (the latest version of XSLT since the summer of 2017 and supported by Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 as well as Altova 2017 or 2018 or 2019) as there you can use e.g. `for-each-group composite="yes" group-by="COUNTRY, COMPANY_NAME, MONTH_OF_BIRTH"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="EMPDTLS">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="EMP" composite="yes" group-by="COUNTRY, COMPANY_NAME, MONTH_OF_BIRTH">
              <EmpGrp>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </EmpGrp>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can test it online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYhU/1.

As for XSLT 2, see https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm for a thorough treatment of XSLT if you have no other text book available or also see the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples which has "A Composite Grouping Key" as the second example by nesting `for-each-group`. Another technique in XSLT 2 is to concatenate the various items composing the grouping key to a string e.g. `group-by="string-join((COUNTRY, COMPANY_NAME, MONTH_OF_BIRTH), '|')"`, making sure the separator character (e.g. `|`) is not contained in any key item value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help..XSLT is looking very simple and easy (as 3.0 version has so many inbuilt functions which allow us to implement in a simpler way)..But ya may be I need to achieve the same using 2.0 versions as well. Thank you so much..